# Will Android PackageManager assign permission if consumer of an app permission is installed before producer?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Scenario: App A defines a new custom permission which is claimed by App B. App B (the consumer) is installed before App A. Will Android PackageManager assign the permission to B? How will permission assignment happen in Android 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

> Will Android PackageManager assign the permission to B?

[No](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md#the-application-sdk-problem-case-c-then-a).

> How will permission assignment happen in Android 6.0?

I am not aware that anything has changed here.

In general, custom permissions are great for pre-installed app suites, and they suck for use by ordinary SDK apps distributed by ordinary means (e.g., the Play Store).

Comment: Thanks for posting. My questions is related to OEM apps that are installed within system directory, not 3rd party apps distributed through Google Play store. Unfortunately, we can't guarantee the install/update order. A coworker told me that this situation can be resolved by having both App A and B define the same permission and then have app B (the consumer) claim it. I am not sure if this is the best practice.

Comment: @Sai: "Unfortunately, we can't guarantee the install/update order" -- I don't understand why, given that you control the firmware. "A coworker told me that this situation can be resolved by having both App A and B define the same permission and then have app B (the consumer) claim it" -- that will only work on Android 5.0+ if both A and B are signed by the same signing key. Unfortunately, that limitation is not in place for older versions of Android, leading to [a security flaw](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: @Sai: "I am not sure if this is the best practice" -- if A and B are signed by the same signing key, then yes, that's probably a best practice, though I don't deal with OEM apps much and therefore don't have much hands-on experience in this area.

Comment: This is strange. In theory, producer app of a custom permission MUST be installed before consumer app can be granted the permission. But in practice, it turns out that this dependency does not exist. I tested on Android 4.4, 5.1 and 6.0, even if consumer of a custom permission is installed before the producer, Android assigns the permission (of course after producer is installed).

Comment: @Sai: That is in conflict with my own testing, outlined [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).